# Hadoop Map-Reduce Parallel execution of 3 Mappers and output to 1 reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a requirement where i have to filter 3 different datasets based on different criteria for each dataset and finally union them and aggregate them in a reducer. I have a Pig script that does the Job, where Filtering of datasets happen sequentially. I would like to know if there is a possibility to run Mappers for each dataset parallely and the output be sent to 1 reducer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using MultipleInputs with 3 mappers for processing the 3 datasets. Refer this link for the API of MultipleInputs - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html

Example :

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, Mapper1.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, Mapper2.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, Mapper3.class);

job1.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
```